# changing the height and width of image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

There is an image of width 450 pixels and height 450 pixels. I want to convert this image o 75 x 75 pixels. How can i do this ?

Comment: There seems to be a solution [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/).

Comment: One image?  Use paint-shop.  Multiple images at run-time?  More complex.  Are they images of schematics or scenery?  What image types (PNG, JPEG, GIF, generated at run-time)? Does the original image have transparency (GIF, PNG), partial transparency (PNG) or animation (e.g. animated GIF)?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson it could be in any format. of any pixels. i am working on a website that has to reduce the pixel to 75x75 and 450x450 for each photo submitted

Comment: A 'photo' would typically not have transparency or animation!  Are all these photos of exactly 1:1 aspect ratio?  That is an unusual aspect ratio for a photo, 4:3 or 16:9 would be more common.

Answer (score 4):

```
BufferedImage scaledImg = new BufferedImage(75, 75, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
scaledImg.createGraphics().drawImage(sourceImg, 0, 0, 75, 75, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [How to resize an image in Java?](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)

```
public class ImageResize {

    private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 75;
    private static final int IMG_HEIGHT = 75;

    public static void main(String [] args){

    try{

        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\image\\img1.jpg"));
        int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();

        BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
        ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", new File("c:\\image\\img1_jpg.jpg")); 

        BufferedImage resizeImagePng = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
        ImageIO.write(resizeImagePng, "png", new File("c:\\image\\img1_png.jpg")); 

        BufferedImage resizeImageHintJpg = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type);
        ImageIO.write(resizeImageHintJpg, "jpg", new File("c:\\image\\img1_hint_jpg.jpg")); 

        BufferedImage resizeImageHintPng = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type);
        ImageIO.write(resizeImageHintPng, "png", new File("c:\\image\\img1_hint_png.jpg")); 

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    }

    private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
    }

    private static BufferedImage resizeImageWithHint(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){

    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();    
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    return resizedImage;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thatz why I mentioned the Reference bellow.